# JSON Response Appended with some number and "|" symbol in it while hitting same request multiple times when we use Apache server with Spring Boot

Tags: ajax, spring, apache, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have a Spring Boot application embedded with tomcat. On top of this, we have apache configured. We have a rest URI which gives us JSON response.  I am generating the response using ResponseEntity class. When we hit the same request multiple times by AJAX, the response is appended with some number segregated with Pipe(|) symbol in it. It's not happening always but, occasionally.  Below is the sample response we get occasional

```
  618|{"key11":"val11","key12":"val12"}{"key21":"val21","key22":"val22"}
```

Below is the sample code generates response:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/loadusersdata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<List<Users>> loadData(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
   ...
   ...
   List<Users> userList = UsersInfoService.getUsersInfo(userDTO);
   return new ResponseEntity<List<Users>>(userList, HttpStatus.OK);

  }
```

The above code works fine in max times. But, when we hit continuously, it gives me the response as shown above in snippet1.

Below are the request and response headers:

```
  **Response Headers:**
    Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-
     transform
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Security-Policy:child-src 'self';
    Date:Wed, 12 Jul 2017 11:01:37 GMT
    Expires:Fri, 11 Aug 2017 11:01:37 GMT
    Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
    Pragma:no-cache
    Server:Apache
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked
    X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
    X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
    X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
    X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

    **Request Headers:**
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Authorization:Bearer 
   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJpbmZ5b3duZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE0OTk4NTcyOTV9.RR-
    VilaC_eNrwXXqkfE024unXpXAm-_P_LoivnGQCOI
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:91
    Content-Type:application/json
    Host:alertuat.coy.com
    Origin:https://alertuat.coy.com
    Referer:https://alertuat.coy.com/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest


 Response Data:
     689|{"userId":95,"user_name":john123, "location":"Uppumpadam Rd, Kannadi-II, Kerala 678701, India",...}[{"userId":96,"user_name":rabkya, "location":"Uppumpadam Rd, Kannadi-II, Kerala 678701, India"...}, {"userId":97,"user_name":venky, "location":"Uppumpadam Rd, Kannadi-II, Kerala 678701, India"...}, {"userId":98,"user_name":john1234, "location":"Uppumpadam Rd, Kannadi-II, Kerala 678701, India"...}, {"userId":99,"user_name":john1253, "location":"Uppumpadam Rd, Kannadi-II, Kerala 678701, India"...},{"userId":100,"user_name":gyan, "location":"Uppumpadam Rd, Kannadi-II, Kerala 678701, India"...}]
```

I am very much new to Spring. Stuck with this issue. 
Immediate help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the complete request and response headers and data? You should be able to get it in Chrome Dev tools. Just sensor anything sensitive in there.

Comment: Strelok, took lot of time to reproduce.  I have added the headers and response data in question.Please check if it can help me out